# Does pandas work on Openshift?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openshift

I am trying to get an application started on Openshift, using the Python cartridge 3.3. I've added my dependencies into the `requirements.txt`, but the application fail to load on pandas dependency. I've searched through the web and there's only [one](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforums.openshift.com%2Finstalling-numpy-and-pandas-with-openshift&ei=gLJzVdieDMaYyASO8ICABw&usg=AFQjCNGX9-8UuYyQ5ttzOwjHYLLU5xnZmw&bvm=bv.95039771,d.aWw) mention of issues related to pandas and numpy but cannot seem to help. I've attempted to install pandas via ssh and end up with the following message after a while

```
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas
Connection to [app].rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
Connection to [app].rhcloud.com closed.
```

Has anyone already used pandas on Openshift? Is there potential issues due to C dependencies?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide any log files from the failed dependencies installation when you do the "git push" ?

Comment: I've been trying to install it, but failed.

Comment: I believe the reason for this problem is that the gear runs out of RAM during the optimisation process of the `algos.c` compilation. See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30814931/604687) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990354/604687) that Fabian links to in his answer below.

Comment: Archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150911000211/https://forums.openshift.com/installing-numpy-and-pandas-with-openshift

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It seems that with OpenShift there's a problem compiling `algos.c`which is part of pandas.

By installing manually I was able to avoid OpenShift's closing of the connection: 
See [my answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814931/cant-get-pandas-to-install-with-openshift#answer-32990354).