# Pip install failed in openshift 3

Tags: pip, openshift, lxml, openshift-client-tools, weblate

I want to use the new platform **Openshift 3** but I can't install **lxml** for **Weblate** with **pip** when build process is launch.

In logs the last line is "**Running setup.py install for lxml**" but no more error

How can I found what happened ?

Thanks

Comment: There is issue for Openshift 3 support on Weblate: https://github.com/WeblateOrg/weblate/issues/1523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Graham I followed this instruction [Pandas on OpenShift v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030744/pandas-on-openshift-v3/46037410#46037410) to edit YAML build configuration

```
 resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the packages around data analytics when compiled with compiler optimisations can chew up too much memory and hit the default memory limit for builds. Try following steps outlined in:

- [Pandas on OpenShift v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030744/pandas-on-openshift-v3/46037410#46037410)

Is less likely, but just in case is the version of `pip` used, add a file `.s2i/environment` and in it add:

```
UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1
```

This will ensure that latest version of `pip` is installed first. This can be required sometimes where a package provides a wheel file. Older version of `pip` used may ignore the binary wheel or get confused in other ways.

Comment: I tried adding 1Gi for the resources > limits > memory setting in the build's YAML file but the build still failed.  Can you please provide steps for how to `add a file .s2i/environment and in it add: UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1`.  I am not sure how to complete those steps.  It is a Python 2.7 application in OpenShift 3 Pro.  Thank You.

Comment: I tried just creating the folder `.s2i` with the file `environment` (with the suggested variable) within it in the local source repository and pushed to GitHub (which triggered a build via webhook), but the build still failed at `Running setup.py install for lxml: started`.

Comment: Set the environment variable ``BUILD_LOGLEVEL`` with value ``9`` on the build configuration and trigger a new build. The logs should then show more detail, including whether the environment file was found in the Git repo and variables set appropriately.