# Deploying a Django App to OpenShift 3.0 that needs NLTK

Tags: python, openshift, nltk, lxml, python-newspaper

I am working on a Django project needing Newspaper3K to retrieve some information over the internet. Trying to deploy my Django web app onto the free OpenShift Online 3.0 Starter, the build fails when it comes to installing the Newspaper3K and hence its dependency NLTK.

Please advise the correct steps to achieve this "Django with NLTK deploying to OpenShift 3" installation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be blocked by the lxml package. The default version of pip fails to compile it. Thanks to the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125643/8583561
I set the environment variable

```
UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=1
```

This should be added to the `.s2i/environment` file.

This enables the PIP to be updated to the latest and the build is completed without an issue.

Comment: Thank you, Graham. I actually used the Web Console for the deployment, therefore set the environment variable through its user interface without adding the `.s2i/environment` file. The setting is under the Environment Tab in the Builds session.

Comment: Yes, can do it under the build configuration in the web console, but easier to make it part of the source code repository. That way you will not forget to add it if deploying multiple instances from the same repo.

Comment: Cool! I did it accordingly and it worked like a magic. Thanks you Graham!