# OpenShift Pro - Initial Build Failing With: Generic build failed

Tags: java, tomcat, build, openshift

I now have a '**test**' Java webapp running and a '**live**' version of the same all on SSL, so things have been going well.

I am now migrating another larger Java webapp from **OpenShift2**. I have created a new project and supplied a git url to build from. I have made the necessary changes locally i.e.. upgraded to Tomcat 8 and Java 8 etc.

All looks well and the build runs for a while and then fails with **Generic build fail** as the error message.

The last lines in the log are:

```
Downloaded: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/1.8.1/plexus-compiler-javac-1.8.1.jar (13 KB at 191.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] Compiling 1358 source files to /home/jboss/source/target/classes
```

I have retried several times and it always ends the same.

Any ideas?

Have I run out of resources?

OpenShift 2 handled this webapp without complaint...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try increasing the resources available to the build. See as an example of how to do that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030744/pandas-on-openshift-v3/46037410#46037410

Comment: Thanks Graham, that sorted it. Your help is much appreciated...