# Getting Openshift 3 container to install numpy and scipy

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, openshift

I have a working Pod for a Deployment in Openshift 3 Starter. This is based off an Image stream from a Docker image. However, I cannot get it to build in Openshift with the inbuilt S2I.

The Docker option is not good as I cannot find setting anywhere to make a Image stream update and cause a redeployment.

I tried setting it up so that a webhook would trigger an Openshift Build, but the server needs python 3 with numpy and scipy, which makes the build get stuck. The best I could do is inelegantly get a Python 3 cartridge install numpy based on `requirements.txt` and the rest via `setup.py`, but this still got stuck. I have a working webhook going for a different app that runs on basically the same layout bar for requirements (Python3 Pyramid with waitress).

- Github: https://github.com/matteoferla/pedel2
- Docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/matteoferla/pedel2/
- Openshift: http://pedel2-git-matteo-ferla.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com

*UPDATE* I have made a [Openshift pyramid starter](https://github.com/matteoferla/Openshift-Pyramidstarter) template.

Answer (score 1):

I would first suggest going back to using the builtin Python S2I builder. If you are doing anything with numpy/pandas, you will need to increase the amount of memory available during the build phase of your application as the compiler runs out of memory when building those packages. See:

- [Pandas on OpenShift v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030744/pandas-on-openshift-v3/46037410#46037410)

See if that helps and if need be can look at what your other options are around using an externally built container image.

Comment: Ah. I struggled with Pandas with v2 for memory reason.
I can increase the resource limit from 512 MB (default) to 1 GB.
I cannot go higher than 1 GB as I am an academic user and they have not released yet any grants. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: I have not seen anyone having issues with needing more memory for when the application is running, it is just the building of the application. The packages get compiled with optimisations enabled which is very memory intensive. So ensure you are changing memory in the build configuration, not the deployment configuration.

Comment: So it is not a memory issue.
I have tried the following:   
* all on requirements.txt file —numpy times out
* all within setup.py with test_requirements='' —numpy vomits some C++ code but says it's fine
* numpy in requirements, scipy in setup.py —scipy cannot find numpy    
In parallel Docker using with centos/python-36-centos7 work for all cases.

Comment: For now I will try to figure out how to push a docker image to the OpSh image stream and redeploy.

Comment: Can you add to your question the actual contents of the ``requirements.txt`` file you are using so I can run some tests. Also confirm which version of Python you are trying to use in Starter. Starter doesn't yet provide Python 3.6 builtin.

Comment: Thanks! When I run from the cartridge I choose 3.5. When I use Docker I use `centos/python-36-centos7`, which is what the link above uses.

Comment: When I use your current repo, it fails, but if I increase memory to 1GB for builds as noted above, it gets beyond that. It then fails because of things you are trying to do in ``setup.py`` with ``requirements``. The ``centos/python-36-centos7`` image will likely work as it is newer and includes a change which means that if you have both ``requirements.txt`` and ``setup.py`` in directory, the ``setup.py`` file will be ignored.

Comment: With the latest way the builders will work, if you really needed ``setup.py`` to be processed, you would need to add ``.`` into the ``requirements.txt`` file. The change is to avoid problems where people have both and didn't want ``setup.py`` processed, now have to be explicit that want it used if also have a ``requirements.txt`` file. Looks like Online doesn't have newer versions of RHEL based S2I builder with change, public CentOS one does.

Comment: Also forgot to mention I also set build time environment variable ``UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=true``. This updates to latest ``pip`` and provides a better chance that binary wheels for packages will be used. The older ``pip`` may not have used binary wheels.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Shall I edit the OP for increased helpfulness for posterity?