# Build always failed while trying to install sharp or node-gyp on openshift v3

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift, openshift-3, sharp

Build always failed with this log:

```
---> Installing application source ...
---> Building your Node application from source

> sharp@0.18.4 install /opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sharp
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/opt/app-root/src/node_modules/sharp/build'
TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/metadata.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/operations.o
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/pipeline.o
```

Trying to build from repo (bitbucket) on openshift v3 with nodejs v6.
Works fine on localhost with nodejs v6.9.2, npm v4.2.0, sharp v0.18.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is cutting off at that point with no obvious error message, you are likely running out of memory for the build. This is not uncommon for npm.

See:

- [Pandas on OpenShift v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030744/pandas-on-openshift-v3/46037410#46037410)

which describes how to increase memory allocated to the build. That is for similar issue when using Python.